# Animated javascript scrollBy

Tags: javascript

I have a next button that when clicked I want it to scroll down the page 517px.

Using the following code (which I have found on another site) I have made a button that does that but I would like it to scroll in a smooth animated way. What would I need to add to do that?

The code I am using is a follows:

```
function scrollByPixels(x, y)
{
  window.scrollBy(x, y);
}
```

and the following on the actual button:

```
onclick="javascript:scrollByPixels(0, 517)"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using any libraries such as jQuery?

Comment: I am using Jquery, yes.

Comment: You can try a plugin: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make repeated scrollBy smoother like jQuery's animate scrollTop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644902/make-repeated-scrollby-smoother-like-jquerys-animate-scrolltop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function scrollByPixels(x, y) {
  $('html,body').stop().animate({
    scrollLeft: '+=' + x,
    scrollTop: '+=' + y
  });
}
```

...or as a simple plugin:

```
$.fn.scrollBy = function(x, y){
    return this.animate({
        scrollLeft: '+=' + x,
        scrollTop: '+=' + y
    });
};
```

**[demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ZVdbG/2)**

Comment: that sorta works. except that when I click it a second time it doesn't do anything. any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @user_1845661 add .stop() before .animate I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @user_1845661 Good :) I've updated it again, now you can even use negative values, to scroll in reverse direction...

Answer (score 1):

To scroll the whole window:

```
var value = $("#scrollToHere").offset().top;

$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: value
    }, 800);
```

Source:
http://blog.alaabadran.com/2009/03/26/scroll-window-smoothly-in-jquery/